# Declaring List in C#

Tags: c#

I was wondering if

```
var list = new List<t>();
```

exactly the same as

```
List<t> list = new List<t>()
```

Is this exactly the same or are there any differences?

Comment: Exactly to you; no, once compiled, yes.

Comment: Well, the second example is missing a `;`. But in all seriousness, did you check out the documentation for [var](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var)?

Comment: Tips, every time you're wondering about these kinds of things, check it on SharpLab https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBLANmgExAGoAfAAQCYBGAWAChyAGAAnOpQG4HyBmNyiwDCLAN4MWktv3IoWAWQAUASjESpGgG4BDKC1zYAzhhYBeFgDsYAdxYAZIxgA82CxgB8K7vQ0aHxlzd3fUdBcytbf2dXDy91SQBfBgSgA

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is totally the same. The compiler will internally replace the `var` with the actual type, inferred from right side of the expression.

In the C# 9 you can also use another type of record: `List<t> list = new()` and compiler will infer the type for the right part from the left one.